# Laravel Backpack "Cannot find 'select2_from_ajax' field view in any of the regular locations"

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am doing local development on Laravel Backpack. My versions:

```
### PHP VERSION:
PHP 8.0.15 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2022 13:47:36) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )

### LARAVEL VERSION:
v8.83.6@dffcec0cb686eafaa3b8f33db11da2cd9d69af1c

### BACKPACK VERSION:
4.1.0@d78f4263f5eef1e7761ba2d55d81959f4de559b6
```

Whenever I am trying to use `select2_from_ajax` or `select2_from_ajax_multiple`, I am getting this error:

```
Cannot find 'select2_from_ajax' field view in any of the regular locations. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\lmsapi\vendor\backpack\crud\src\resources\views\crud\inc\show_fields.blade.php)
```

Any idea why is this causing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’re using the FREE version of Backpack, but trying to use a PRO field.

Some of the features, like “select2_from_ajax”, are only available if you instal the PRO add-on (paid). Here’s a comparison of the FREE vs PRO features: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/features-free-vs-paid